# Validity of Proofs, and what is terated as a Proof?

Tags: evidence, commerce, banking

If a product delivery from an e-commerce company was canceled due to their own logistic issues.

Later their chat system which is an automated bot confirms the product cancellation and refund date.

Yet the refund is not posted on my credit card.

The bank, with whom chargeback is filed, disregards the recording of the chat on the merchant e-commerce website and asked for an email confirmation.

e-commerce denying email confirmation.

Is this chat recording not the relevant proof?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Mastercard customer-service protocols are not the law.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this chat recording not the relevant proof?

That's up to the bank to decide (and also by the upstream payment system e.g. Visa).

Chargebacks are contractual matter between you and the bank. How they work, what proof required etc. is set out in the credit card terms and conditions of service which you have accepted.

There are no laws that would compel the bank to accept forms of proof for chargebacks notwithstanding the terms.

If the bank doesn't help, your recourse is to sue the e-commerce company. And perhaps find a more flexible and customer-friendly bank for future transactions.